# Display icon in notifiaction FirefoxOS

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os, web-notifications

I want display an icon in Notofication Firefox OS for that I use this code :

```
var img = './images/icon-30.png';
var notification = new Notification('Notification', { body: 'Body Notification', icon: img });
notification.addEventListener('click', function() {launchSelf();});
```

In the Desktop the icon display well

[image]

but the icon not display in mobile ( Firefox OS Simulator )

[image]

what is the problem ? Any idea ? Thanks.

### Update

If I get the icon from the url like this : https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/app-tab-bar-icons-for-ios/30/User_login.png the icon display well in the simulator, So I think the problem is the path :/

NB: I use Firefox OS 1.3 and the size of icon is 30 x 30

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [tsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications](https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications)

> The icon that will be set as a custom overlay for IE and notification
>   displayed from Chrome running on Windows. Note that icon by default is
>   not required for Chrome, Safari & Firefox, but is required for IE. In
>   order to unify the implementations, the icon should be always provided
>   in order to display notifications for all supported browsers. icon
>   param could be String with icon's location, but it could be also an
>   Object with the following properties: {"x16": Icon for IE only. The
>   icon should be 16x16px *.ico format, "x32": **Icon for all other
>   browsers(Chrome on Windows, Firefox). The icon's size should be
>   32x32px, supported formats: jpg/png/ico**}. Once again - Safari and
>   Chrome on MacOS does not allow icon to be set. **For Firefox Mobile, the
>   icon is always Firefox icon.**

Try using a 16x16px or 32x32px size icon.

Comment: Yes I try, but not working, and I update my question

Comment: The icon in your question is still 30x30

Answer (score 1):

joschi70 has a working answer, but you can avoid the replace operation like this:

```
var img = window.location.origin + '/images/icon-30.png';
```

(I'm assuming you've set the origin field in the manifest.)

Separately, you should probably use a 32x32 icon for Notifications (though the Firefox OS launcher wants a 30x30, sigh).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I tried it too without any success. It seems it's a bug on Firefox OS with relative paths as local files https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=980567 .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Frédéric Harper, this is a bug in FirefoxOS.
What seems to be working if you construct an absolute path like this:

```
icon: window.document.URL.replace(/^(.*\/).*/, "$1") + "img/notification_logo.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

I "forge" an absolute url for the reference...

I used this function:

```
function getURLResource(path)
{
    // notice that index.html is the launchpath of your app
    var url = window.location.href.replace("index.html", "");

    return url + path;

};

// In your case you can do something like that:
var url = getURLResource("images/icon-30.png");

console.log(url);
// Will print something similar to this:
url = "app://<identifier>/images/icon-30.png";
```

Hope it helps you,

Luís Augusto Weber Mercado.